# "find_element_by_id" method doesn't show up from the selenium wedriver class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Only two find methods show up. I don't seem to know where the issue is coming from[1]

**Please see the picture in the link below for better understanding**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGoBC.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that you've provided or are trying to search `find_element_by_id` was provided in the Selenium 3 documentation and could have been used like

```
driver.find_element_by_id('element_id')
```

However, starting Selenium 4, these methods are deprecated. So now to use any kind of locator, you need to have `driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")`

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


svc = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")  #url that needs to be passed

elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element")
elem.click()

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The class you're using doesn't have that as a method. You can verify this in the docs.
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

Not sure what you're trying to do and how else to help, maybe you're looking for another class, or you can use the existing find_element method?

Comment: I've gotten a solution. Apparently there is a new method to find eleemnts on selenium web driver. For example it loooks like this now "driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")"

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method provided by Selenium.  find_element_by_id is robot framework implementation for its SeleniumLibrary.  Way to locate by id:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginForm')
```